# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in user.js

Tags: node.js, backend

```
var router = require("express").Router();
var User = require("../models/user.js");

router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
    var user = new User();

    user.profile.name = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne( { email : req.body.email }, fucntion(err, existingUser) {
        if(existingUser){
            console.log(req.body.email + "already exists");
            return res.redirect("/signup");
        }
        else{
            user.save(function(err, user){
                if(err) return next(err);
                res.send("New user has been added");
            });
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `fucntion` is it a typo here? or that may be the reason of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you replace **fucntion** to **function**

```js
var router = require("express").Router();
var User = require("../models/user.js");

router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next){
    var user = new User();

    user.profile.name = req.body.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne( { email : req.body.email }, function(err, existingUser) {
        if(existingUser){
            console.log(req.body.email + "already exists");
            return res.redirect("/signup");
        }
        else{
            user.save(function(err, user){
                if(err) return next(err);
                res.send("New user has been added");
            });
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```